# HashMap only has one element instead of three

Tags: scala, functional-programming, hashmap

I am filling a HashMap in Scala like so:

```
val hashMap = new HashMap[P, List[T]]() { list.map(x => put(x.param1, x.param1.elements)) }
```

The problem is that `hashMap` will have only a size of 1 while `list` has a size of 3.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You''re mixing imperative commands (`put`, `new HashMap`) with functional constructs (`map`). This cannot behave nicely.

What you should do (if I understand your goal correctly):

```
list.map(x => x.param1 -> x.param1.elements).toMap[P, List[T]]
```

Also, beware that if several elements in your list have the same `param1`, only the last one will be kept, since `Map` can only have one value for a given key.

Comment: "This cannot behave nicely." Yes, it can. It's just rarely what you actually want.